# Animated sci-fi movie with a white girl with red hair who had a metal armor and sword

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

The lead is a white girl with red hair. She had a metal armor and sword. One scene I can remember was in like a garbage disposal place, but in space. It had robots, normal looking like robots. There was one guy I remember who was evil. I think it's from the early 2000s. I saw it on TB. The movie had comics like animation, not anime. I keep connecting it to Red Sonja, because I think that's what I remember her name was. Maybe it's not.

Comment: Heavy Metal? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtBcwDY9D_M / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5O98xCpDYk

Comment: Can you recall anything that might help? Animation style (western / anime), her name, the names of any other characters, what she was dressed like, the name or type of vessel she was on in space, what the robots looked like?

Comment: There isn't much to go on here, you'll need to add more details. Please  check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: This is still very vague and will likely be closed. If you remember anything else you can edit it into the question even if it is closed. If you do that, we will see it again and might be able to help you at that point.

Comment: Hmm, I immediately thought of [_The Fifth Element_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fifth_Element), but it's probably not.

Comment: Sounds like Star Wars.